# Why do the persist() and cache() methods shorten DataFrame plan in Spark?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, caching

I am working with spark version 3.0.1. I am generating a large dataframe. At the end calculations, I save dataframe plan in json format. I need him.
But there is one problem. If I persist a DataFrame, then its plan in json format is completely truncated. That is, all data lineage disappears.

For example, I do this:

```
val myDf: DataFrame = ???
val myPersistDf = myDf.persist
  //toJSON method cuts down my plan
val jsonPlan = myPersistDf.queryExecution.optimizedPlan.toJSON
```

As a result, only information about the current columns remains.
But for example, if you use spark version 3.1.2, then there is no such problem. That is, the plan is not cut.
It is also worth saying that if you do not call the toJSON method, then the plan is not cut:

```
// Plan is not being cut.
val textPlan = myPersistDf.queryExecution.optimizedPlan.toString
```

I made a small test project to make sure of this:
https://github.com/MinorityMeaning/CutPlanDataFrame

[image]

Please help me figure it out.
I need to get the full plan in json format.

UPD(1):

Now I'm trying to convert each node to json separately. Now it doesn't work perfectly, but I think we need to go in this direction.

```
val jsonPlan = s"[${getJson(result_df.queryExecution.optimizedPlan).mkString(",")}]"

  def getJson(lp: TreeNode[_]): Seq[String] = {
    val children = (lp.innerChildren ++ lp.children.map(c => c.asInstanceOf[TreeNode[_]])).distinct
    JsonMethods.compact(JsonMethods.render(JsonMethods.parse(lp.toJSON)(0))) +:
      getJson(t.asInstanceOf[TreeNode[_]])))
      children.flatMap(t => getJson(t))
  }
```

UPD(2):

OK, here's how I finally solved this problem.
I downloaded spark 3.0.1 from github. Then replaced the TreeNode class in this project with a file from spark 3.1.2. Recompiled the project.
As a result, I received a package spark-catalyst_2.12-3.0.1.jar
Which replaced the existing original packaging.

There is no option to switch to another version of spark. I have not found any other solutions to the problem.
Thank you guys for prompting. Your advice helped.

Comment: Could you assign bounty to me if my answer helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cherry pick below 2 commits into spark 3.0.1 to fix this issue.

```
* 1603775934 - [SPARK-35411][SQL][FOLLOWUP] Handle Currying Product while serializing TreeNode to JSON (8 months ago) <Tengfei Huang>
* 9804f07c17 - [SPARK-35411][SQL] Add essential information while serializing TreeNode to json (9 months ago) <Tengfei Huang>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll sit and watch!

Comment: I found changes concerning my problem. Can I use them in my custom code by saving the current version of spark? https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/32557/files/6b836cc31619f260219f154686d8a8198a48a706

Comment: You can cherry pick both commits by keeping current version.

Comment: What does it mean to choose, what do you mean, sir?

Comment: Do you mean I need to recompile the spark package by inserting a modified file?

Comment: Yes, first using `git cherry pick`, then `./build/mvn -DskipTests clean package`. You can refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#buildmvn

Answer (score 0):

Well, you already kinda have your answer.

TLDR: Upgrade.

You could, could, look into the [github repo](https://github.com/apache/spark/commits/branch-3.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/LogicalPlan.scala) at the logical plan code, and look for difference in how logical plans are calculated between. 3.0.1 and 3.1.2. (Or look at the code for persist and see how it's changed.) You could then back port a patch to 3.0.1.  But you'd still need to build a new version of spark and then deploy it so that the plan returned. But if you are doing all that work why not upgrade to 3.1.2 if you know it works?  (Or some later version of Spark?)

(You must have some dependency on a sub-component that only compatible with 3.0.1?)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to upgrade to version 3.1.2 yet. There are custom classes that depend on version 3.0.1.

Comment: Well I see you already opened a bug for this (That's good), but your only option really is to find a fix and patch your own custom 3.0.1 blend.  If you need this soon, I suggest your start working on it.  I couldn't see any obvious pulls that looked to fix this. But I'm sure one of the patchees does it.  Is it faster to do that or faster to re-write the custom classes to work with 3.1.2?

Comment: Still, I'll try to redo the optimizedPlan method, as it was done in version 3.1.2. Or vice versa. I'll look at older versions of this method. Maybe they'll do. Or it may be necessary to redefine the toJSON method. We'll see.

Comment: How do I approach this problem? Can I carefully pull the optimizedPlan method functionality from another version of spark?

Comment: That is what I"m suggesting.  You need to back-port (pull code from later builds) into 3.0.1 custom build.  until you find the 'magic' that fixes your bug.  The alternative is to debug 3.0.1 build and trace it until you find the issue, fix the code and deploy your 'fixed' version.